# Rewrite URL requests for an .html extension to lowercase, remove extension and then add trailing slash

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm working on a WordPress website that has some '.html' in the root folder (previous developer) and I need to **convert all requests made for a `.html` only**.

For a successful script it needs to:

1. remove `.html` extension
2. convert all chars to lowercase
3. add a trailing slash
4. (obviously) still be able to grab the requested file

This is my solution so far and **it does everything except convert the URL to lowercase** and also causes no conflicts to the WordPress URL structures:

```html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1_$2.html [L]
```

### EDIT:

I take it back. The above script didn't do what I needed it to do so I am open to all suggestions for this that use the `.htaccess` file in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your Apache configuration to use mod_rewrites *RewriteMap* directives:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteRule (.*?[A-Z]+.*) ${lc:$1} [R]
```

See the Apache manual here: [Redirect a URI to an all-lowercase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int).

Important note from the documentation:

**Per-directory and .htaccess context**

> The RewriteMap directive may not
>   be used in  sections or .htaccess files. You must declare
>   the map in server or virtualhost context. You may use the map, once
>   created, in your RewriteRule and RewriteCond directives in those
>   scopes. You just can't declare it in those scopes.

Comment: Thanks @mayersdesign. Do I place this in the `.htaccess` and then before or after the script I already have? Also, I need this to only affect `.html` extensions

Comment: From the official documentation it is mentioned that The RewriteMap directive may not be used in sections or .htaccess files. You must declare the map in server or virtualhost context. You may use the map, once created, in your RewriteRule and RewriteCond directives in those scopes. You just can't declare it in those scopes.